# Delegation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, delegation

I have a class `Klass`, and its constructor accepts an argument. We should be able to call methods on this object that are not defined in `Klass`.

We can chain multiple methods, but in the end, we have to use `Klass#result` to get the result like:

```
Klass.new(5).pred.pred.result
```

and the output here should be `3`. I tried using `method_missing` in `Klass` and using `send` on the object's class, but that would have worked without the `result` method that I have to use. Can someone explain how this can be done with delegation?

Comment: `Klass.new(5).pred.pred.result` is a massive violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). You should rethink your design. Perhaps just have one method call to `self.get_result_for_second_pred_of(number)` and do all the work within the `Klass`?

Comment: It is not my design and I can't unfortunately. I have to work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class Klass
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  def result
    @number
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block)
    if @number.respond_to?(method_name)
      @number = @number.method(method_name).call(*arguments, &block)
      return self
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    # be sure to implement this...
  end
end

puts Klass.new(5).pred.pred.result # => 3
```

But it's problematic. In this particular example, since #pred returns a new object (it doesn't modify the object it was called on), we have to reassign the instance variable to the result. It works for pred and other methods that return new Integers, but some methods on Integer don't return an Integer (e.g. [Integer#even](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F)). In this case you'd get this sort of behavior:

```
puts Klass.new(4).even?.result # => true
```

Depending on your particular situation, that might be what you're after. Or, it might be that in your situation all methods the object being delegated to mutate that object, rather than return new instances of the object, in which case the reassignment isn't needed.

I don't think you can use Ruby's existing Delegator and SimpleDelegator constructs, because the only way you can chain the final #result call onto the end is if every delegated call returns the instance of Klass. Using those existing constructs would cause delegated calls to return their normal return values, and the chaining would then be on whatever objects those return values return. For example, using the above code, you'd see this behavior:

```
puts Klass.new(5).pred.pred.class # => "Klass"
```

Using SimpleDelegator, you'd see this behavior

```
require 'delegate'

class Klass2 < SimpleDelegator
  # Klass2 methods...
end

puts Klass2.new(5).pred.pred.class # => "Fixnum"
```

Hope that helps.